# Required validation Dropdownlist filled with values from another table MVC - ASP.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, drop-down-menu

We are some students from Belgium and are working on a project for the last 3 weeks. 
Now we got stuck on our validation for our dropdownlist that we have filled with values from another table. 
The Required validation message doesn't work.
We have searched for it but it seems that we can not find our problem.

Here is the code from our Domain class - lid (member in english) 
this is the part where we have the foreign key, so we need the value from Status_lid to fill our dropdownlist

```
 //Foreign key naar de tabel "Status_Lid"
    [DisplayName("Status")]
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "status is verplicht")]
    public int StatusLidID {get; set;}
    public virtual StatusLid StatusLid { get; set; }
```

Here is the code from our lidcontroller (membercontroller), where we get the values from the other table.

```
  public class LidController : Controller
{
   //this is the code for using our Business layer 
    private IStatusLidBLL StatusLidBLL = new StatusLidBLL();

  //this is the code for fill in out dropdownlist
  ViewBag.StatusLidID = new SelectList(StatusLidBLL.GetAll(), "StatusLidID", "Omschrijving");
```

And here is the code from our view create.aspx, when we create a new lid ( new member) we have used the string.empty, because we wanted to be sure nothing is selected and if nothing is selected and the users click on submit, it would display a errormessage.

```
        <div class="editor-label">
        <%: Html.LabelFor(model => model.StatusLidID) %>
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        <%: Html.DropDownList("StatusLidID", String.Empty) %>
        <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.StatusLidID,"Gelieve een status op te geven") %>
    </div>
```

We are struggeling a bit on this problem and we hope you could help us out! 
thank you verry much in advance!

Comment: Do you check for ModelState.IsValid in your Post method in controller?

Comment: @Zaki yes we do. we have the standard if statement with the modelstate.isvalid

Comment: so if you select empty in dropdown and submit, would IsValid be false or true?

Comment: Well it doesn't but now it actually works. I always tested the program without filling out the other fields, now I actually did. And it gives me the message I have set in the view. Thanks anyway! @Zaki

Answer (score 0):

[Code](http://crazzynewsindia.blogspot.in/p/collection.html)

visit this link you will find from this ...

remove  String.Empty

you remove from this then its work.....